# VS2015 project crashes under x64 platform

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015

I am running an Asp.Net Razor application in VS2015. When I run in x64 debug mode, I get the following error:

```
[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyWebApp.DAL' 
or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made 
to load a program with an incorrect format.]
```

```js
Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MyApp.DAL' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = MyApp.DAL
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: MyApp.DAL | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/MyApp/MyApp.WebApp/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\MyApp\WebApp\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\...\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\...\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/76dd151c/b29594f/MyApp.DAL.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/76dd151c/b29594f/MyApp.DAL/MyApp.DAL.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.
```

If I modify the build proprties (Debug-->Properties menut item) to "Active (Debug)" with Platform set to "Active (x86)" - all runs fine.

I do have .Net Framework 4.6.1, product version 4.6.01055.
And as per RegEdit:

```
  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client\1033]
 "Version"="4.6.01055"
 "TargetVersion"="4.0.0"
 "Install"=dword:00000001
 "Servicing"=dword:00000000
 "Release"=dword:0006041f
```

Help is appreciated so I can get this to run under x64 Platform.

Bob

Comment: I've added Platform (x86) to my solution's Configuration Manager (Buid-->Cgf Mngr), and running under x86 worked. My project now runs. Why it doesn't run under Any Cpu, or under x64 - I still do not understand.

Comment: Look at the Project Properties < Build of the MyApp.DAL project. That project's build settings for Platform target should be Any CPU

Comment: @ChrisMarisic - I can't believe the answer was that simple. Yes, it works under "Any CPU". Please add as your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Project Properties < Build of the MyApp.DAL project. That project's build settings for Platform target should be Any CPU